# Key Error sure.AssertionBuilder object at

Tags: python, django, bdd, lettuce

After pulling with rebase changes from VCS I am getting a Key Error when trying to run my Aloe_Django(porting from Lettuce) tests. Before it was working fine, now we can not figure out what we did wrong.
The Error is

KeyError:< sure.AssertionBuilder object at 0x7fbf588172e8>

The error occurs in registry.py file in lines :

`def append_to(self, what, when, function, name=None, priority=0):
        """
        Add a callback for a particular type of hook.
        """
        if name is None:
            name = self._function_id(function)
        funcs = self[what][when].setdefault(priority, OrderedDict()) #HAPPENS HERE
        funcs.pop(name, None)
        funcs[name] = function
    # pylint:enable=too-many-arguments`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a lonely person asking and answering her own question :D
The problem was in importing, which we were not even using, so deleting this line resolved our problem. Hope it would be helpful for someone in the future

`from sure import basestring`